# How to create a map of different key-value data types in ADF with associate function?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

in Azure Data Factory I have a dataflow that takes a xml and transform it to a JSON.

One of the key-value pairs of the output JSOn must have the following structure:

```
"load": {
      "cargo": {
        "netWeightLoad": 0,
        "unit": "KG"
      }
```

After flattening the xml, I have the "netWeightLoad" and the "unit" in two different columns named load_cargo_netWeightLoad and load_cargo_unit respectively.

To have the desired JSON output, I am trying to associate these two columns into a map using the 'Derive Column' transformation and there the 'associate' function this way:

```
associate('cargo', associate('netWeightLoad', load_cargo_netWeightLoad, 'unit', load_cargo_unit))
```

[image: associate_function]

However, it throws an error because the data types are different (load_cargo_netWeightLoad is integer and load_cargo_unit is string). The erros says: ***Type of keys and type of values must respectively match for associate function.***

**Is there a way to be able to map these columns while preserving the data types?**

I know I could convert the load_cargo_netWeightLoad to string, but that is not an option for me, I need to preserve the data type. I tried to look for alternatives, like keyvalues function, but without success.

Comment: Can you provide your desired output for the above input?

Comment: Hi, complete output should be like this:

[
  {
    "aircraftRegistration": "DABYI",
    "airlineSpec": {
      "division": "FRA",
      "flightSequenceNr":,
      "flightType": "NA",
      "missionId": "EUC",
      "reportedCustomer":,
      "riskHolder": "LH"
    },
    "load": {
      "cargo": {
        "grossWeightLoad": 0,
        "unit": "KG"
      },
      "pax": [
        {
          "ageGroup": "Ad",
          "paxCheckin": 0
        }
      ]
]

Comment: Can you provide the input format as well?

Comment: few fields from input not expected in output, thanks!
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<flx xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='http://www.fuelplus.de/flxXML/v2.0'>
 <Flight mode='flight'>
  <FId>
   <Dte>2024-01-11</Dte>
   <Reg>TC</Reg>
  </FId>
  <AlSpec>
   <Div/>
   <SeqNr/>
   <RepCus/>
   <RskHld>X</RskHld>
   <FlTyp>E</FlTyp>
   <MisId/>
  </AlSpec>
  <Load>
   <Pax>
    <I>2</I>
    <C>3</C>
    <F>4</F>
    <MA>5</MA>
   </Pax>
   <Cargo>
    <CWt u="u1">5</CWt>
   </Cargo>
  </Load>
 </Flight>
</flx>

Comment: Not the XML input. You mentioned you already did flatten this right. can you provide that flatten transformation output image for better understanding?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, in the meantime I figured it out, I didnt have to use the associate function, I could directly derive columns by using the '@' in the expression builder, like: @(netWeightLoad = load_cargo_netWeightLoad, unit = load_cargo_unit) and this would create a complex type column where each item within can have its own data type. Thanks anyway for the support.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to use the associate function; I could directly derive columns by using the '@' in the expression builder, like:

`@(netWeightLoad = load_cargo_netWeightLoad, unit = load_cargo_unit)`

This would create a complex type column where each item within can have its own data type.